# How to trigger GET request from another GET request in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have a GET request that gets form data, then I need to trigger a second GET request on a different route that gives the form data to a REST API. I can do this manually through Postman, but I'd like the first GET request to trigger the second.

This is the idea:

```js
app.get('form', (req,res,next) => {
    //Get form data
    //Pass form data
    //Trigger next request
})

app.get('API', (req,res,next) => {
    //Get data from previous request
    //Use data in params
})
```

I would really appreciate any feedback! So far I've found posts talking about app._router.handle, but haven't been able to implement it correctly.

Comment: You can store the callback handlers as variables. Once the `form` GET request has been called, you simply invoke the function for the `API` GET request.

Comment: You can use axios npm package to make API request from one to another

Comment: You can do it another function in which result of first-get-request to be fed to call next get request.

Comment: @ryeballar could you post a sketch of what the function for the API GET request might look like? I'm having trouble envisioning that!

Comment: @DeekshithHegde could you please give me a phrase I could google that with? Or a link to what that might look like?

Comment: @sanjeevRm is there any chance you could give me an example of a function like that?

Comment: await axios.get(`url`)
            .then(response => {
            // Your response will be in response.data
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass data between middleware, you must assign it to request object like :

```
app.get('form', (req,res,next) => {
    const { user, tags } = req.body
    
    // assign this
    req.data = { user, tags }
    
    // pass to next  
    next()
})

app.get('API', (req,res,next) => {
    // get the passed data
    req.data
    console.log(req.data)
})
```